# Text Views in Grid Views disapearing on grid view scroll

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am having issues with androids grid view. When I scroll, some text views disappear. I have a conditional statement that checks a value in the database and hides the text views based on that. But that conditional statement is only meant to be for the views in the grid that meet the criteria. However, when scrolling all views seem to change.

Here is my custom array adapter (I have also attached an image to show what I mean):

```
![public class ArrayAdapterHandler extends ArrayAdapter<Day> {

    public Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Day> days = new ArrayList<Day>();

    public ArrayAdapterHandler(Context context, int dayId,
            ArrayList<Day> days) {
        super(context, dayId, days);
        this.layoutResourceId = dayId;
        this.context = context;
        this.days = days;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView day_text;
        TextView situps_text;
        TextView crunches_text;
        TextView legRaises_text;
        TextView plank_text;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Day day = days.get(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.day_row, null);
            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(0x30BFFF1E);
            } else {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(0x30CCCCCC);
            }
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.day_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.day_text);
            holder.situps_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.situps_text);
            holder.crunches_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.crunches_text);
            holder.legRaises_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.legRaise_text);
            holder.plank_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plank_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.day_text.setText(String.valueOf(day.getDay()));

        if (day.isCompleted() == 1 || day.isRestDay() == 1) {
            // Hide all the activity values which are 0 anyway.
            holder.situps_text.setVisibility(4);
            holder.legRaises_text.setVisibility(4);
            holder.plank_text.setVisibility(4);
        }
        if (day.isRestDay() == 1) {
            holder.crunches_text.setText("REST DAY");
        } else if(day.isCompleted() == 1) {
            holder.crunches_text.setText("COMPLETED!");
        } else {
            holder.situps_text.setText(String.valueOf(day.getSitups()) + " situps");
            holder.crunches_text.setText(String.valueOf(day.getCrunches()) + " crunches");
            holder.legRaises_text.setText(String.valueOf(day.getLegRaises()) + " leg raises");
            holder.plank_text.setText(String.valueOf(day.getPlanks()) + "sec planks");
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

![Scrolling issue image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB3uL.png

Thankyou.

Comment: make sure you have `else` part for all the `if`s

Comment: After `convertView.setTag(holder);`, set the tags for your textviews and check. Like `convertview.setTag(R.id.day_text, holder.day_text);`. Do it for all the textviews and check. And are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I have closed all if statement with else statments and have added the convertView.setTag(R.id.day_text, holder.day_text) for each text view. The problem is still there though. Is my custom adapter correct?

Comment: Sorry, I see what is wrong. I was setting the text views after closing the if statement. I moved it in the if statement and now that issue does not occur. The issue that is occurring now is the views seem to be swapping places on scroll.